# SMS sender application using API

Tags: api, http, sms

I want to make a program that will communicate with a database that has name, mobile number, etc. and send them SMS messages in different occasions through HTTP API provided by a service provider. I want the database and the application to be running in an external server and go through list of names every day to send messages. Please give me a head start on what would be an appropriate programming language/database and where can I host my application. I can send SMS through HTTP request that the service provider has

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [LAMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_%28software_bundle%29) stack is pretty accessible (Linux/Apache/MySQL/PHP), and you could accomplish what you describe with a few simple PHP scripts and a cron job - assuming that you just need to send messages once a day.

If your messages are also scheduled for specific times, then it might be wise to move to a stack that persists in memory - as it could continuously check the schedule more easily than PHP's single request model. Perhaps [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) if this is something you need, Javascript is also pretty accessible.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the programming language that i´m most familiar with. Since the application is simple a simple .csv file would probaly enough unless you have > 5000 numbers to send to. Personally a use [GleSYS](http://www.glesys.se) VPS for hosting my SMS applications and i use [46elks SMS AIP](http://www.46elks.com) to send SMS this combination woks very well for me. If you have very little demands you may try to use a Raspberry PI.

I use Python or PHP for most smal funcation.